# SAP .NET Connector, working with X509 certificates

Tags: x509certificate, sap-dotnet-connector

We had a C# application connecting to SAP backend systemes using the SAPSSO technology. There has now been a need to replace this with X.509 certificates.

When using SAPSSO, the orginal code would make an HTTP call to the target system, and get a cookie containing the ticket to use:

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
ticket = response.Cookies["MYSAPSSO2"].Value;
```

That ticket would then be passed to the RfcCustomDestination object to facilitate a secure connection:

```
prms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SAPSSO2Ticket, ticket);
```

The problem is, I can change the enumerated value from SAPSSO2Ticket to X509Certificate,

```
prms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.X509Certificate, ticket);
```

but when I do this, no ticket can be returned from the response, since a MYSAPSSO2 cookie is no longer provided.

So how can I generate the needed ticket value for an X509 certificate?